# New to coding; Can't get button to link to new activity in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, button

It opens the first activity on the emulator, but fails on button click. I created the second activity (AddProductActivity), so maybe I did something wrong there.  I've tried all the variables I could find online to change how the button operates.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.content_main)
       val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goToAddProduct)
       button.setOnClickListener {
       val intent = Intent(this, AddProductActivity::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
       }
   }
}

class AddProductActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.add_product)
   }
}
```

on content_main.xml:

```xml
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToAddProduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_to_inventory"/>
```

Comment: show us the error message

Comment: In order for me to help, I think I need to know the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have registered your new activity in the manifest. This is a common mistake by newcomers.

[image: android manifest xml]

If that is not the case before you click on the button open your logcat view in android studio. Once you click on the button please investigate the crash issue from here.

[image: logcat view on android studio]

Comment: Please accept my answer, if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks